# ES6 Map object to group values

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I want to convert this array:

```
[{
  department: 'HR',
  person: 'Tom'
},{
  department: 'Finance',
  person: 'Peter'
},{
  department: 'HR',
  person: 'Jane'
}];
```

Into this one, grouping people by `department` and changing the keys

```
[{
  role: 'HR',
  people: ['Tom','Jane']
 },{
  role: 'Finance',
  people: ['Peter']
}]
```

I use this technique that have seem around and works really well, I am not really sure if it's got a name.

```js
const data = [{department: 'HR', person: 'Tom'},{department: 'Finance',person: 'Peter'},{department: 'HR',person: 'Jane'}];

function groupPeopleByDepartmentWithObj(data) {
  const obj = {};
  for (const { department, person} of data) {
    if (!obj[department]) {
      obj[department] = { role: department, people: []};
    }
    obj[department].people.push(person);
  }
  return Object.values(obj);
}

console.log(groupPeopleByDepartmentWithObj(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Using the ES6 Map object I can do the same with this

```js
const data = [{department: 'HR', person: 'Tom'},{department: 'Finance',person: 'Peter'},{department: 'HR',person: 'Jane'}];

function groupPeopleByDepartmentWithMap(data)  {

  const mapper = new Map()
  for (const { department, person} of data) {
    if (!mapper.has(department)) {
      mapper.set(department, { role: department, people: []}) 
    }
    mapper.get(department).people.push(person)
  }
  return Array.from(mapper.values())
}

console.log(groupPeopleByDepartmentWithMap(data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Is this approach better in any way, is there another way to use `Map` to get the same result?

Comment: When you say `Is this approach better` what do you mean? Are you trying to (prematurely perhaps) optimize the performance of your code? Or are you looking to find bugs?

Comment: Maybe this question is better placed in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I just mean, is there any point of using Map for this task?

Comment: You're asking for opinions and opinion based questions are not a good fit for SO

Comment: Using a Map will preserve the original order if you have numeric values for `department`, using an object won't (eg: you'll get two different orders if `department` was changed to have `2` instead of `'HR'` and `1` instead of `'Finance'`). You'll also get different results between the two if `department` holds object types. In terms of speed, I've heard that using a Map is faster, but never tested it myself, as speed for something like this shouldn't be of concern really

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a fundamental difference between *object properties* and *keys* in a key-value store.

A property is something you define at the coding time, it has a fixed name and a well-defined meaning. A property is similar to a variable or a function.

A key is something that is only known at the run time, it is dynamic and has no inherent meaning except being associated with some value. A key is like an array index.

In the past, javascript `Object`s were misused to emulate key-value stores, using property names as keys. This had several serious drawbacks

- property names, and  hence keys, can only be strings
- properties are generally not ordered
- key iteration is clumsy (`hasOwnProperty` etc)
- since there's no difference between properties and keys, a dynamic key can accidentally overwrite a defined property, and vice versa, an existing property can be mistaken for a key

The `Map` was invented to address these drawbacks specifically:

- `Map` keys can be anything
- `Map` keys are always in insertion order
- key iteration is well defined
- keys and properties live in separate namespaces and don't overwrite each other

Therefore, if you need a key-value store, `Map` is always a better choice. Using generic Objects for this is a mistake.

As for the "better" way to use Maps for grouping, this is rather subjective. I'd prefer a more generic version

```
/// data: an Iterable
/// keyFn: a function which will be applied to each data item to obtain its group key
/// returns: a Map(key => [items])

// function groupBy<T, K>(data: Iterable<T>, keyFn: (x: T) => K): Map<K, T[]> 
//
function groupBy(data, keyFn) {
    let m = new Map();

    for (let x of data) {
        let k = keyFn(x);
        if (!m.has(k))
            m.set(k, []);
        m.get(k).push(x);
    }

    return m;
}
```

which can be used like this for the task at hand:

```
let result = [];

for (let [role, items] of groupBy(data, x => x.department))
    result.push({role, people: items.map(x => x.person)})
```

Comment: So are you saying the second snippet is more fit for the task?

Comment: @Álvaro: yes, that's what I'm saying ;)

Comment: Thanks, regarding the other question is there a better way to do it with `Map`? as I am merely replicating what I did with the object.

Comment: Actually that code pushes an array into the `people` array

Comment: @Álvaro: yep, fixed